# Android Studio Recording button disabled on Oppo device

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-recording, oppo

There is a very handy feature in Android Studio which allows to record screen of the phone while it is connected via USB cable. I use it a lot, but on one particular device it doesn't work. The button is just disabled for no particular reason and I cannot figure out why. Screenshot button works fine though. And running my app as well.

This only happens on this device. I also have a Pixel and screen recording works fine.

[image]

I have Oppo Reno 8 device running Android 11. I had it connected to my MacBook M1 with type-c cable and had "Developer Options -> USB debuging" option enabled on the phone. I use Android Studio Electic El 2022.1.1 (p1).